# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'dtime' before initialization

Tags: grapesjs

> working in grapesjs  in [component in js](https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Components-js.html#components-js)

```
  //Date time


        // Define a new custom component
                editor.Components.addType('comp-with-js', {
                    model: {
                        defaults: {
                            dtime,
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Create a block for the component, so we can drop it easily
              editor.Blocks.add('test-block', {
                    label: 'Test Date',
                    content:`
                     <div id="demo"></div>
                    `,
                });

        const dtime = function() {
            const dt = new Date();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dt;
        };
```

> get error
> **ReferenceError: Cannot access 'dtime' before initialization**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can't access dtime before initialization

```
//Date time
    
   
    const dtime = function() {
        const dt = new Date();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dt;
    };

    // Define a new custom component
            editor.Components.addType('comp-with-js', {
                model: {
                    defaults: {
                        dtime,
                    }
                }
            });

    // Create a block for the component, so we can drop it easily
          editor.Blocks.add('test-block', {
                label: 'Test Date',
                content:`
                 <div id="demo"></div>
                `,
            });
```